# Do not set session key as authorized if http basic auth is used in spring security 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a RESTfull server in Spring mvc+Spring security+Hibernate. Here is config of HTTP:

```
<http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    create-session="ifRequired">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="restSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="restFailureHandler"
        login-processing-url="/api/user/login" username-parameter="login"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="WSESSIONID"
        logout-url="/api/user/logout" />
    <csrf disabled="true" />
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

I get a resource with the following command:

```
curl -X GET -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" http://localhost:8082/api/user
```

And the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node0rprji8vkthhw1f5juvgotpknj1.node0;Path=/
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"id":1,"version":0,"login":"admin","firstName":"","lastName":"admin","email":"admin@dpq.co.ir","language":"fa","timeZone":"Asia/Tehran","joined":1496458546000,"lastLogin":1496458546000,"administrator":true,"staff":true,"active":true}
```

as you can see, there is Set-Cookie command in response header. I`m looking for a way to not set cookie if a basic auth is used.

Comment: Why do You use this ' delete-cookies="WSESSIONID" ' ?

Comment: I try to remove session key if user is login (not as basic auth) and want to logout.